# internal vs external uri on fetching data from mediastore

Tags: android, external, internal, mediastore

Hopefully someone can clarify this to me...I am working on a simple video player app that plays video clip stored on phone.

All examples I've seen fetch video using MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI content Uri, something like that

```
cursor = resolver.query(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cols, whereClause, null, sortOrder);
```

But won't it limit the list to only files stored on SD card?

Newer android phones has significant amount of internal memory - for example, Samsung Galaxy S typically comes with 16Gb on internal memory and 2Gb sd card.

Should I scan mediastore twice with external content uri and internal one?

Again I saw like 10 examples for audio and video players and all of them use external only.

Even [checked source code for the stock music player](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=blob;f=src/com/android/music/VideoBrowserActivity.java;h=e8aaf7480bfe5c5a72343e66b516921045b804fc;hb=refs/heads/froyo-release) and it also pulls only from external card.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ran some tests and it seems the answer it depends. On android emulator and HTC mytouch it fetches only items on external SD card, while on Samsung Galaxy S it actually pulls from internal storage too.

This is the part I really hate about android - why such simple things are so different

Comment: external and internal storage differ in terms of what can be accessed not the physical location of the data. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654774/android-is-external-content-uri-enough-for-a-photo-gallery/30655498

Answer (score 1):

Try using `MediaStore.Video.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI`