# What does "MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI" do?

Tags: android

I am trying to build a simple android app which takes photo from camera and shows it in an image view.

I am confused what `MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI` mean and do

Here is the code:

`Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI); startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

Comment: see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30654774/android-is-external-content-uri-enough-for-a-photo-gallery

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand that, it would be nice if you give the explanation and the relevant code as answer.

Answer (score 0):

In android external storage not means external drive but anything external to application. Even "File Explorer" and "Gallery" seems to act as external for an application.

`(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)`, this will go to external storage like gallery and pick the image and return it in from of a Uri data.

Here is an example function to pick the image from the gallery:-

```html
fetchImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent image = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
        image.setData(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(image,1000);
    }
});
```

This will simply make an intent whose job is to pick the content(Intent.ACTION_PICK), then using intent object we try to fetch the data(Uri) from the gallery and then start the activity passing intent "object" and "RequestCode".